# Storing search queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

i have fairly big site with approx 100 000 searches per day.

my mysql is currently causing very high load on the server and i suspect my table with stored search queries to be the reason.

right now the mysql table has only 2 columns: date and query. i add new queries every time someone searches for something and then another script deletes queries older than 24 hours. there are last 30 queries displayed on the website, sorted by the date.

may this be the reason for the high load? would adding column with ID or using any other method for storing the searches make a big difference? thx

Comment: let see... count the rows on your search table. That said i think you need to store the date, the query and the result to not launch that query too much.

Comment: Do you have an index on the date column? Also, use `EXPLAIN` to get some basic profiler information.

Comment: This is quite a broad question.  There could be many different reasons for such a high load on your database.  Are you sure that this is your bottleneck?

Comment: Inserting and storing them wouldn't cause performance issues, it would just take up a lot of space, however querying that take for anything specific repeatedly would cause a slow down.

Comment: result of explain: http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/4308/5hig.png

Comment: Storing the "result" of the query may can unload a little of the load on the server if the query to obtain the result is lighter than the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reviewing your indexes and possibly adding some specialized tools for searching, like Sphinx.

I suggest you start by running `EXPLAIN` query on the search query.

If your table has a lot of writes, you should not use MyISAM engine, as it locks all table, not only the row. You should probably use InnoDB engine.

Comment: i switched to InnoDB, lets see if it changes something.

Comment: looks like the switch to InnoDB actually helped quite a lot! the load went down from 10-30 to 2-6!

Comment: @user1394013 Could you show the query? From the EXPLAIN you can see that no indexes are used, but it's hard to tell without the query what indexes should be added.